# Overcome the coercion of dataframe to a list when using sqldf

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf, coercion

I need to classify the rows into two groups(`Present` or `Not present`) based on the values in the two columns `Var1`, `Var2` in the dataframe `pum`. Later add this as a new column to another dataframe as `data.cov.cat$PU`. When `Var1` greater than `0.053` or `Var2` in the set of values `c(1,2,3)`, the rows needs to be marked as `Present` else `Not present`.

The below piece of code is developed on the conditions.

```
data.cov.cat$PU <- sqldf("SELECT CASE WHEN Var1 >= 0.053 THEN 'Present'  
                                   WHEN Var1 < 0.053 OR Var2 IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Present'
                                   WHEN Var1 < 0.053 OR Var2 = 0 THEN 'Not present'
                                   ELSE 'NA' 
                              END as newCol
                              FROM pum")$newCol
```

The command executes properly and the output is as expected except the dataframe `data.cov.cat` is coerced to a list.

Could you please suggest how to avoid the coersion of the dataframe to a list.

Reproducible example:

```
data.cov.cat <- data.frame(V1 = runif(10,0,10), V12 = c("blue", "red", "yellow", "pink","blue", "red", "yellow", "pink", "red", "yellow"))

data.cov.cat <- sapply(data.cov.cat, as.factor)

pum <- data.frame(Var1 = runif(10,0,1), Var2 = c(1,3,2,0,2,1,2,0,1,3))

data.cov.cat$PU <- sqldf("SELECT CASE WHEN Var1 >= 0.053 THEN 'Present'  
                                   WHEN Var1 < 0.053 OR Var2 IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Present'
                                   WHEN Var1 < 0.053 OR Var2 = 0 THEN 'Not present'
                                   ELSE 'NA' 
                              END as newCol
                              FROM pum")$newCol
```

As the original data.frame has columns factorized, I am converting them here as well.

Comment: Which "data.frame" is converted to a "list" - "pum" or "data.cov.cat"? Could you provide a sample dataset that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @alexis_laz I have added an example, could you please have a look at it.

Comment: Even with the edit it is still not reproducible since `data.cov.cat` is missing.   Also if you are going to use random numbers a `set.seed` statement is needed to make it reproducible.  The output from `sqldf(...)$newCol` is a character vector as expected but we can't really say more based on the information provided.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I have added the information. I want to add this new character vector as a new column in the existing dataframe. Is it possible ?

Comment: "data.cov.cat" is converted to a "matrix" after the `sapply` call. And `$<-` is only valid for "data.frame"s or "list"s. If you use `data.cov.cat[] = lapply(data.cov.cat, as.factor)` or `data.cov.cat = as.data.frame(sapply(data.cov.cat, as.factor))`, then you'll get the desired output, because "data.cov.cat" is now a "data.frame".

Comment: @alexis_laz Thank you for showing mistakes and teaching different possible ways to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Can you(who has downvoted the post) please help me in understanding the issue with this post, as it will help me in understanding what went wrong, resolve the issues and will avoid me getting blocked from this useful site(I got a warning in asking the question)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.cov.cat` is not a dataframe before the last `sqldf` statement executes. It has been changed to a matrix when `sapply` got executed. The solution to the reproducible example is:

```
data.cov.cat <- data.frame(V1 = runif(10,0,10), V12 = c("blue", "red", "yellow", "pink","blue", "red", "yellow", "pink", "red", "yellow"))

data.cov.cat <- as.data.frame(sapply(data.cov.cat, as.factor))

pum <- data.frame(Var1 = runif(10,0,1), Var2 = c(1,3,2,0,2,1,2,0,1,3))

data.cov.cat$PU <- sqldf("SELECT CASE WHEN Var1 >= 0.053 THEN 'Present'  
                                   WHEN Var1 < 0.053 OR Var2 IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Present'
                                   WHEN Var1 < 0.053 OR Var2 = 0 THEN 'Not present'
                                   ELSE 'NA' 
                              END as newCol
                              FROM pum")$newCol
```

Now, the coercion is not faced.